# Source .zshrc is restarting my iterm2

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I don't know what I've changed but whenever I run the command:

```
source .zshrc
```

My iTerm2 restarts itself, and then the changes takes effect. However, it was working fine previously.

Is there a place where I can check my error log for the `source` command?
Thanks.

EDIT: I've unchecked the option `Automatically close a session when it ends` in my Profile Settings and when I try to source, it gives me:

```
================= Broken Pipe =================
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue with `zsh-autosuggestions` plugin.
Please update your plugin to newest version.
[Here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/126) is some hint about this issue.